# Proximity Kit:Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=17

Tags: ios, proximity, geofencing

Right now I am using proximitykit.framework to do geofencing.
I found out this sample:https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/proximity-kit-ios-example and I got this error:"ProximityKit[Error] Ranging Beacons Failed with Error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=17 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 17.)" I also tried to build up this app in my iPhone4,but this app quit automatically.

here is the method I used:

```
    - (void)proximityKitDidSync:(PKManager *)manager {
        NSLog(@"Did Sync");
}

    - (void)proximityKit:(PKManager *)manager didEnter:(PKRegion*)region {
    NSLog(@"Entered Region %@ (%@)", region.name, region.identifier);
}

    - (void)proximityKit:(PKManager *)manager didExit:(PKRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Exited Region %@ (%@)", region.name, region.identifier);
}


    - (void)proximityKit:(PKManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)ibeacons inRegion:   (PKIBeacon *)region
    {
    for (PKIBeacon *ibeacon in ibeacons) {
        NSLog(@"Ranged UUID: %@ Major:%ld Minor:%ld RSSI:%ld", [ibeacon.uuid UUIDString],   (long)ibeacon.major, (long)ibeacon.minor, (long)ibeacon.rssi);
    }
}

    - (void)proximityKit:(PKManager *)manager didDetermineState:(PKRegionState)state  forRegion:(PKRegion *)region
{

        if (state == PKRegionStateInside) {
        NSLog(@"State Changed: inside region %@ (%@)", region.name, region.identifier);
    } else if (state == PKRegionStateOutside) {
        NSLog(@"State Changed: outside region %@ (%@)", region.name, region.identifier);
    } else if (state == PKRegionStateUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"State Changed: unknown region %@ (%@)", region.name, region.identifier);
    }
}

    - (void)proximityKit:(PKManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"The Error: %@", error.description);
}


    - (void) alert:(NSString *)format, ...
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
        va_end(args);

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Proximity Kit"
                                                        message: [NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%@", str]
                                                   delegate: nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beacon Ranging requires Bluetooth Low Energy support.  This is not available on the iOS simulator or on a physical device prior to the iPhone 4S or iPad 3rd generation.